# When is HSV-1 most contagious?

Tags: disease-transmission, herpes-simplex

It is possible to pass HSV-1 at any time even if your symptoms are currently dormant, but the risk of contagion is higher during outbreaks. When does the risk of contagion return to it's dormant level? Is there some type of graph depicting the changes in the contagion risk over the course of the outbreak?